# Небольшая проблемка при использовании файлов произвольного доступа

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *fptr;
int main (void)
{
    char letter,f;
    fptr=fopen("/home/badbad/C/bookInfo1.txt","r+");
    fseek(fptr,-1,SEEK_END);
    for(letter=0;letter<88;letter++)
    {
        f=fgetc(fptr);
        printf ("%c",f);
        fseek(fptr,-2,SEEK_CUR);

    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0 ;
 }
```

Пожалуйста, объясните почему в терминале после того как прочитывается файл выводится **ubububububu**, я понимаю что 88 символов это много, но хочется понять почему такой бред выводится.

Comment: fseek возвращает ошибку при попытке вылезти за левую границу файла, но вы эту ошибку никак не обрабатываете

Comment: аааа, спасибо) Так это оказывается проще простого исправить

Comment: @andreymal, а как это исправить?))))

Comment: Например, выйти из цикла при возникновении ошибки?

Comment: @andreymal, ну, я пишу if(fptr==1)
  {
   break;
  } а мне компилятор выдает ошибку

Comment: Потому что бессмысленно сравнивать fptr с чем-либо. Читайте документацию про fseek